# Can't change a vector's element value at index i

Tags: c++, vector, primes

In Stroustrup's *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*, chapter 4, exercise 13, I have to write a program to find all the prime numbers in a given range using the Sieve of Erathostenes.

So far, I have come up with this:

```
vector<int> values;

void initialize_values()
{
    for (int i{0}; i < 100; ++i)
        values.push_back(1);
}


void remove_composites(vector<int> values)
{
    for(int i{2}; i * i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (values[i] == 1)
        {
            for (int p{i + i}; p < values.size(); p += i)
                values[p] = 0; //not working
        }
    }
} 


int main()
{
    initialize_values();
    remove_composites(values);
    
    for (int i{2}; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (values[i] == 1)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

I create a vector with size 100 (in this first case) and initialize elements to 1. Then I check all indexes multiples of `i` while `i * i < 100` and change the value at those indexes to 0 and finally print the indexes whose value is 1.
The problem is that `values[p] = 0` is not assigning the value 0 to the element at index `p` and I don't really understad why.

**EDIT** So after reading comments and answers I decided to move all code under `main()`, because I don't know how to use references.
The goal of this exercises, according to the book, is to get used to processing user input, working with loops, iterations, etc. It's not intended to be professional nor expert at this point.

To all people with many years coding and answering questions here, remember you were once learners and beginners. Have some respect and don't turn this community into a toxic one.

Updated code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> values;
    for (int i{0}; i < 100; ++i)
        values.push_back(1);
    
    for(int i{2}; i * i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (values[i] == 1)
        {
            for (int p{i + i}; p < values.size(); p += i)
            {   
                //cout << p << " ";
                values[p] = 0;
            }
            //cout << '\n';
        }
    }
        
    for (int i{2}; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (values[i] == 1)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

And works as expected:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why pass the parameter if it is already global...? But it shouldn't be. You could make it local to `main()` and just pass (`const`) references to it. Let this be a lesson early that pass-by-value is the default!

Comment: @Sai Sreenivas Could you explain a bit? Your comment is not useful.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem is that `values[p] = 0` is not assigning the value `0` to the element at index `p`

It *is* assigning it.

The problem is that you are operating on a *copy* of the original vector, and that copy is local to `remove_composites`, which is why the calling code doesn’t see the changes.

Change your function signature to use a reference type parameter: `std::vector<int>&`.

There are also some other issues with your code (using the wrong type, i.e. `int` instead of `bool`; inconsistent signatures; mutable global variables).

Comment: Ok. I can't use references because I haven't reached that chapter yet. This isn't supposed to be a industrial-grade program, only simple enough to get me started. Should I make everything in ```main()```?

Comment: @FacundoFlores If you haven’t reached references yet, use a return value (this is my preferred way anyway), i.e. *return* the filled vector. Incidentally, `initialize_values` should *also* return a vector (and take an argument that specifies the size, rather than hard-coding the value 100), and the global variable `values` should be moved into `main` as a local variable.